# How to do that button action as a direct command

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button that call function `togglemenu` at `self.navigationController`. It works properly.

```
[btnMenu addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

---

How Can I call it as a direct command? Like:

```
[self.navigationController toggleMenu]; // Not working
```

Comment: What do you mean, "not working"? What's happening?

Comment: Calling it directly will work if you import the navigation controller subclass, and cast self.navigationController to that class as Sumit Mundra said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
[self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(toggleMenu)];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two method to do this

```
1) [self.navigationController performSelector:@selector(toggleMenu)];

2)  get your customenavigtion contoller class instanse and call this method

 NavigationViewController *navigationController = (NavigationViewController *)self.navigationController;
   [navigationController toggleMenu];
```

Answer (score -2):

simply you have to use `[self toggleMenu];` for method calling

Comment: It`s not possible as it`s a function from my custom self.navigationController class.

Comment: `No visible @interface for 'MyViewController' declares the selector 'toggleMenu.`